# Overriding IP address

Tags: networking

I have a network with few devices with IP addresses 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3.
I have access to devices 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.3 (both linux).
A program is running on 192.168.1.2 and connecting to 192.168.1.1 using udp socket, I cannot modify that program.
How can I make the program on 192.168.1.2 to connect to 192.168.1.3 instead? I can run anything on 192.168.1.2 even on root permissions (hopefully something that can change IP addresses) and before the program is run. A link to API guide on this will be helpful (C#/C++/Perl), although a working program will be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use iptables on x.x.x.2 to redirect to x.x.x.3 instead of x.1. Post your q. on serverfault or superuser for details. It has nothing to do with programming.